# How to Convert Material Displacement to a Mesh?

Tags: node-editor, baking, displacement

So I created this complex (for me) node network to create mountains. I didn't sculpt them, it's just a plane subdivided a lot with a subdivision surface mod. So the actual mountain is only visible in render mode. So in 3d space it's just a plane. My question is: How can I make the displacement as actual mesh? Like in 3d view I can see and edit the mountains. I want to do this because: 1) decrease render time and 2) I want to create a village underneath the mountain.

Please tell me the process of how to do this. I tried searching for tutorials but all of them already have a high poly mesh that the want to bake. I hope you will understand what I want and go easy on me because this is new for me :)

[image]
the rest of the images:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqKn1.jpg

[image]

I baked my noise nodes and in the bake settings used the emit option. I got a black and white image and saved it as a openexr because I used a 32 bit image. Then I used a displacement mod with the image I baked. But I'm getting only a small part of my mountains. What did I do wrong?

[image]

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

what i get with normal in displacement mod
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrrbQ.jpg

Answer (score 10):

What you can do is using a *Displace* modifier instead of a *Displacement* node.

To get the same result as your current 3D reliefs, you need to save the black and white image texture you're using in your *Displacement* node.

Either this image is already existing as one unique image and in that case it will be easy to load it into your *Displace* modifier, or it's made of a mix of several nodes, in that case I guess you'll need to bake the b&w texture.

To do so, make sure you're in *Cycles Render*, plug your nodes so that the b&w composition is displayed as a diffuse image on the surface of your plane. Create a new *Image Texture* in your *Shader Editor*, don't plug it into anything, inside this *Image Texture* click *New* to create a new black image, call it *Displace Image* for example, keep this node selected.

In the *Render* panel > *Bake*, choose *Bake Type* > *Diffuse*, disable *Direct* and *Indirect*, enable *Color*, click on *Bake*, the image called *Displaced Image* should now be the b&w displacement image.

Once you get your b&w image, use it in the *Displace* modifier: Create a *Displace* modifier, click on *Texture > New*, in the *Properties* panel > *Texture*, in the dropdown menu, select *Displaced Image*.

With the same b&w image, you'll have the same effect, on the left *Displacement* node, on the right *Displace* modifier:

[image]

Comment: Maybe mention floating-point, linear EXR? Also, out of interest, I've always used Emission, and I _think_ you can get away with 1 sample. Do you know?  I'll have to run through some basic tests to reassure myself.. trying to get my head around what happens where.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about actually  ;)  maybe give your own answer to elaborate what you mean?

Comment: Thank you for the response! I did what you told me but I'm only getting a partial result. Instead of getting my mountains im getting little slops... See my edited post for the image. How do I fix this? @moonboots

Comment: did you use the exact same b&w picture (or were you able to bake it correctly if it was necessary?)? Also, have you tweaked the Displace strength factor?

Comment: @AntonPg, also, in the Displace modifier, I think you should choose Direction > Normal

Comment: If I tweak the strength factor it shifts the mesh a lot. Although I'm getting some more mountains with strength 5 it shifts the mesh. I edited my post

Comment: How do I know how much strength I need to match exactly with my original mountains? @moonboots I'm getting better result with normal thanks :)

Comment: Maybe share your file (make sure you pack all the images)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109770/discussion-between-moonboots-and-antonpg).