# Creating 3D printable 3D-texture on faces with nodes?

Tags: node-editor, image, texture-baking, displacement, 3d-printing

Newbe with Blender!
(v2.9)
Want to set up a correct Nodes-chain in the Shader, to perform:

- a 3D-texture on only **one** face of, say ,a cube
- **from** a jpg **image**, defining the **displacement** along the normal of that face (for ex a .jpg image of a brick surface)
- with **size**/translation/rotation capabilities of applied texture.

I tried a lot:...(I am newbe, and watched a lot of videos...!).
My last tries:

- in edit mode: subdivide the cube ..
- in shader pane: add texture coord node, mapping node, image node, displacement node

but I dont know how to connect these nodes (especially the displacement node) correctly !
I dont'care about rendering, my purpose is **3D-printing** of the model only!
Thanks

Comment: Hello :). For 3D printing, have a look at the Displacement modifier. You'll need to convert the displacement into real geometry for exporting, which isn't possible with nodes.

Comment: Related: [How to Convert Material Displacement to a Mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/183873/78972)