# Can you use the displacement node to actually affect the mesh?

Tags: node-editor, displacement

I hope the image below describes what I mean. The rendering shows the type of effect that I want but when looking at the mesh, it's still just a cube. Can I make the displacement node actually affect the cube? I've turned on experimental render and bump and displacement on the settings.

The displace modifier does do exactly this but I want to be able to use the nodes, not just a texture.

[image: Render]

[image: Mesh]

Comment: I guess you need to do it through the Displace modifier

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Convert Material Displacement to a Mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183873/how-to-convert-material-displacement-to-a-mesh)

Comment: Hi Dan, and welcome to our Stack Exchange.  

There are several questions on this topic, including https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183873/how-to-convert-material-displacement-to-a-mesh which suggests burning a displacement map from the material and then using it with the modifier.

If you need it to be truly dynamic, geometry nodes might be the modern way of accomplishing your goal.