# How do I get displacement from a material to mesh geometry?

Tags: mesh, materials, displacement, procedural

I'm having trouble with displacement. I'm trying to follow the instructions [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/materials/components/displacement.html?highlight=displacement) to get the procedural pitting I have from the material on to the mesh itself so I can export it as an .stl for 3D printing. As shown below, I've tried using the displacement node to no effect. I've also tried using the displacement modifier, but in that case I'm not sure how to pipe in the material.

I've also tried the instructions [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183873/how-to-convert-material-displacement-to-a-mesh), but no dice with that process--too much stuff has moved since then. Any help for a noob would be greatly appreciated!
[image]

Comment: Can u show us your try with the displacement modifier? Because this is the way you can go…

Comment: Are you using Generated coordinates or UV coordinates for your shader ? (the input of the noise texture)

Comment: I'm not sure about your setup, why do you plug the Bump into the Displacement? Plug the ColorRamp into the Displacement instead. Also don't forget to switch to Cycles and in Material > Settings > Surface > Displacement, choose Displacement and Bump

Comment: Thanks to everyone for trying to help!
@moonboots I used the same ColorRamp that was going into the bump for the displacement and changed the Material setting from "Displacement" to "Displacement and Bump". No changes to the underlying mesh though

Comment: @Gorgious I've zoomed out, hope that answers your question.

Comment: yeah that's why it doesn't work with the displacement modifier : it uses UV coordinates. Look up UV unwrapping

Comment: @Gorgious I've already set my seams and unwrapped. I used a texture to control the density of a geometry node effect. I've zoomed out so you can see what I mean--the density of the block is controlled by a texture I UV mapped by hand so the blocks could favor one side of the bangle. So I know how to UV unwrap, I just need to know what I'm aiming for here. Thanks again for all the help!